# Best way to store / retrieve huge amount of unique strings in android

Tags: android

I want to write android application.  This Application will show all words,  which matches user defined pattern.
  So I need to choose storage , to store 300 000 unique words (6-8 MB in size)

---

There are criteria to consider:

- regex support (like operator is not sufficient)
- performance
- data must be stored locally

---

Unfortunately, Sqlite database doesn't have regex support.Shared Preferences has memory problems (I can't save 6-8 MB data in them).

Can someone point me on correct && optimal  way?

Comment: To avoid many opinion-based (biased) answers; tell us what you're permitted to do. Maybe a local file in the `/data/data/your.package.name` folder is enough.

Comment: Is local file good for performance limitations?

Comment: There are no performance limitations unless you're looking for real-time performance. But nothing Android offers is really good for real-time performance :/
Since you're working with a file up to 10mb, I **think** you'll be just fine, but testing and profiling will give a better answer to that.

Comment: I was thinking these strings uniqueness would help me in something ...

Answer (score 1):

Dump you data in a local file in the /data/data/your.package.

Build an AsyncTask and execute with:

```
executeOnExecutor(java.util.concurrent.Executor, Object[])
```

Method above invokes true parallel execution. More on the subject can be read here : [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

If your goal is real-time performance, design the application in way, where the user doesn't notice the work going in the background (this is the not so technical aspect of the question).